# Que veut dire le mot « chui »?

Tags: usage, argot, oral

Récemment j'ai vu le mot « chui » sur le web et je ne l'ai pas trouvé dans le dictionnaire.  La phrase entière était :

> et moi chui américain.

Cela veut dire quoi exactement ?  Quelqu'un peut-il m'expliquer ?

Comment: Chui sûr que cela veut dire « Je suis »

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*chui* est une contraction de mots comme dans les exemples suivants:

- *ché pa* = je ne sais pas
- *g pa* = je n'ai pas
- *chui* = je suis

Comment: Je n'associerais pas « chui » aux SMS.  C'est une approximation graphique d'une forme vocale qui existait bien avant les SMS.

Comment: De ce que je me souviens, _chui_ a d'ailleurs poursuivi sa route au Québec pour finir comme _chu_

Answer (score 36):

*Chui* est une contraction familière. L'écriture littéraire est *J'suis* et se prononce plus ou moins comme « chui ». La phrase complète étant *Je suis*. Donc en pratique, il s'agit de *Je suis* où l'on ne prononcerait pas le `e` de *Je*, créant ainsi une liaison entre le *J'* et le mot qui suit (ici *suis*). La contraction du son « J » avec le son « S » donnant pratiquement le même son que « ch ».

Ce type de contraction apparait souvent à l'oral, *J'sais pas trop* (littérairement abrégé) est une contraction de *Je ne sais pas trop* qui devient *ché pas trop* en langage familier ; Similairement on trouve *Faudrait qu'tu t'presses un peu* à la place de *Il faudrait que tu te presses un peu*.

En général c'est souvent le `e` qui est supprimé dans ce type de contraction, mais pas toujours. Exemple : *T'aurais pas une clope ?* / *Tu n'aurais pas une clope ?*

Comment: « La contraction du son "J" avec le son "S" donnant pratiquement le mème son que "ch". » Plus précisément, je pense que la présence du son [s] dévoise le j, puis que, toujours par simplification, le s tombe. En résumé, je suis [ʒə.sɥi] -> j'suis [ʒsɥi] -> ch'suis [ʃsɥi] -> chui [ʃɥi].