# What "Chuis" means in this context?

Tags: sens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Que veut dire le mot « chui »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/839/que-veut-dire-le-mot-chui)

> Donc, sous l'effet du choc, mes yeux se ferment puis s'ouvrent d'un coup. Et après, **chuis** réveillée et de super bonne humeur pour la journée.

This was part of a story I was reading. However, I can't find the meaning of this word, even in Google Translate.

Comment: See also http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/839/que-veut-dire-le-mot-chui

Comment: For Discworld's nerds : Granny Weatherwax's “I atten't dead” is translated as *“Chus pas morte”*.

Comment: Chuis même sulcu.

Answer (score 12):

« Chuis » means in all contexts that I know « je suis. »
(Derived like: Je suis -> j'suis -> chuis )

This is a very informal, kind of lazy, way to talk.
You probably won't hear it from people above 40 (as of today).

Comment: In some parts of Québec, "chuis" is sometimes even further shortened to "chu".

Comment: @Saeed Neamati: Where did you see it written down? We rarely encounter this kind of spoken language written down outside blogs and such like. I must admit I do not read teenage literature, I might be surprised if I did!

Comment: @Laure [Queneau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Queneau)? I don't know if he used *chuis* specifically, but he's a famous author, often studied in school, who wrote down a lot of spoken language.