# When can "j'suis" be used?

Tags: usage, prononciation, oral

I presume *j'suis* is slang for *je suis*.

That much for the lexical formation of this "expression," which has been detailed [elsewhere](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/839/que-veut-dire-le-mot-chui).

However, I don't know the contexts in which it can be used. Is it considered an offensive way of speaking, a derogatory way of speaking, or a perfectly harmless way of speaking between friends and family?

Can children tell their mothers, in a spoilt brat manner, *J'suis*?

So what I'd actually want to know is a few details about its usage in the language nowadays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say it is perfectly harmless in any context but the most formal. And even in the most formal setting, I can hardly see it to be of any consequence. I would even go further and say it is systematically used by everyone who does not pay a particular attention to eloquence. In every day conversation, *not* using it makes you stand out.

It is, however, completely different if you intend to *transcribe* a conversation. Then it might come out a bit childish or disrespectful.

Comment: Having lived in various regions of Eastern Canada where the Shiac and Acadian varieties of French are spoken, it is also common for '_j'suis_' to be abbreviated even further to the point where it almost sounds just like '_suis_'.  Although this can be a mix between people just saying '_suis_' and people just really touching the 'j' sound _so_ lightly that it sounds like '_suis_'.  I have less experience with the Quebec dialect but I believe this happens there too.  Perhaps someone with experience with the Quebec dialect could confirm this.

Answer (score 8):

*J'suis* actually stands for *je suis*. This is an informal [elision](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/elision).

This is spoken language, so you will normally not be led to read/write this, but in certain songs or dialogues. And this is not offensive at all, this is only *je suis* badly/quickly pronounced. *J'suis* sounds a bit like *"chui"* and this is why you sometimes read *chui* on internet forums or SMS.

So can children tell their mother *j'suis*? As this is a matter of prononciation, actually, they do, and this is accepted or not:

> — Franck, où es-tu ? 
>  — J'suis là, Maman !
>  — Et bien viens vite à table, c'est prêt !

or

> — Franck, où es-tu ? 
>  — J'suis là, Maman !
>  — On dit *Je suis* mon chéri ! Faudra-t-il que je te le répète chaque jour ?