# Identify what the speaker said

Tags: transcription

In this clip, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18RWhV7clW8&ab_channel=Mastu, from 12:45-12:48, what does the lady say? Is it « super sûre »?

Comment: Chus pas sûre probablement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She says twice:

> *Chui pas sûre* (Je suis pas sûre).

See [Que veut dire le mot « chui »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/839/que-veut-dire-le-mot-chui)